# Why can't I iterate over a timer in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

This is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

int _ta = 0;
 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (_ta < 1)
            {
                _ta++;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_ta);

            }
```

But the `WriteLine(_ta);` doesn't stop after 1 time, it just continutes. Why? How can achieve this effect?

**EDIT:**

Im sorry, I wasn't clear enough:

I meant:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_ta);
```

This still happens, even though _ta is bigger then 0.

Comment: What is your question? I'm confused.

Comment: What makes you think incrementing a counter will stop the timer?

Comment: What would that even mean? A timer is not a collection, how would you iterate over it?

Comment: You use a timer to set up a recurring event... It's supposed to continue on because you never disabled it in the first place.

Comment: you are right, I am sorry please see EDIT

Comment: Are you saying that you're getting numbers larger than 1 printed?

Comment: no 1 is always printed but it shouldnt after the first time because _ta is bigger then 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have read your question along with answers and your comments.
I see you don't understand one thing: `The variable '_ta' will be reinitialized with 0 on every request` and that's why you keep seeing '1' being printed all the time.

You have some reasons to use Timer in non standard way - but this doesn't matter.

If you want any variable to persist between subsequent requests from the same user, you should use `session` to store the variable - all is described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: So there is new requests just from the timer ticking?

Comment: Exactly. The timer ticks on the page in the browser. On every tick, page issues AJAX request to server, the handler is executed on the server and response is sent back to the browser. It works this way because: 1. Handler is a server side code, 2. Server can't send any data to the client (browser) in any other way than by responding to a request, 3. There is no main loop on the web server side hence no way to implement Timer.

Answer (score 2):

Reading between the lines it sounds as though you only want the `_ta` variable to be printed once (or as long as it is less than zero).

I suspect you are not telling us something because your code works correctly if I reproduce it in a new `Winforms` project.

You can verify this for yourself by creating a new Winforms project, adding a button to the form and adding the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    int _ta = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_ta < 1)
        {
            _ta++;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This should only be called once...");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(_ta);
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This should be called every tick...");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

The above program gives the following output:

[image]

Comment: yes it works on Winforms, but not in asp.net.

Comment: What is actually happening? Remember the web is stateless so information is not retained. I've never used webforms but I would have thought that each time you click the button a new request would be made which would mean that the `_ta` variable and the timer will be re-initialised. I wouldn't have thought a timer would make sense in a web application.

Comment: @Benjamin: They do. Think about an auto-updating chart embedded in a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I iterate over a timer in asp.net?

I don't know what *you* mean by this. Taken literally, because `Timer`s don't represent sequences.

> But the timer doesn't stop after 1 time, it just continutes. Why?

Because that's what `Timer` is designed to do. It keeps ticking until you disable it.

> How can achieve this effect?

What effect? To only tick once? If so, disable it after the first postback.

Stop and think for *just* a second. You have a [timer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000FTS9S6) in your hand, maybe some device you purchased on Amazon. It's [instruction manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx#introduction) says that when you enable it, it will ring every ten seconds. Now you're asking us why after the first ring, it rings again ten seconds later. Because that is what it was designed to do. And you want to know how to not have that effect? Turn it off!

Comment: You need to provide us with the *smallest* and clearest working example that exhibits the behavior your describing because that should not be the case if implemented correctly.

Comment: I did, check above. It's my exact code but on asp.net not winforms!

Comment: That is not a working example. It's a code snippet.